# Perfect $\mathbb Z_\ell$-modules

Tags: homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, p-adic-numbers, higher-algebra

**Disclaimer** : I asked this question on Maths.StackExchange 20 days ago (and started a bounty) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723218/perfect-mathbb-z-ell-modules) but got no answer, so I'm asking it here now (with no modification).

$\newcommand{\l}{\ell} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}$
I'm trying to understand a remark in *Weil's conjectures for function fields I*, by Gaitsgory-Lurie.

Specifically it's remark 2.3.4.3., which essentially states the following : an object $M$ in $\mathrm{Mod}_{\mathbb Z_\l}$ is perfect if and only if it's $\l$-complete and $M\otimes_{\Z_\l}\Z/\l$ is perfect in $\mathrm{Mod}_{\Z/\l}$ (this latter condition implies that this is also true for $M\otimes_{\Z_\l}\Z/\l^d$, for any $d\geq 0$)

They state it without proof, and it looks like there is no proof elsewhere in the book (as far as I can see, although I haven't checked the whole book).

What is clear to me is the forward direction : indeed $\Z_\l\otimes_{\Z_\l}\Z/\l$ is perfect over $\Z/\l$ and $\Z_\l$ is $\l$-complete, and these conditions are closed under retracts, so the sub-$\infty$-category of those $M$'s that satisfy the latter conditions is a stable subcategory, contains $\Z_\l$ and is closed under retracts so it contains all perfect $\Z_\l$-modules.

The reverse direction, however, does not seem so clear. I think one ought to use the fact that the $\infty$-category of $\l$-complete modules is equivalent to $\underset{d}{\varprojlim} \mathrm{Mod}_{\Z/\l^d}$ but that doesn't seem to be enough since we want $M$ to be compact in the whole $\mathrm{Mod}_{\Z_\l}$, not just in $\l$-complete modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over a PID, you can check perfectness on homology. So the claim is that the homology of an $\ell$-complete $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-module is finitely generated if and only if it is so mod $\ell$. The homology groups are $\ell$-complete, and so this follows from the long exact sequence of mod $\ell$-reduction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand the end. What do you call the long exact sequence of mod $\ell$-reduction ?

Comment: Well, for any complex $X$, you have a cofiber sequence $X\xrightarrow{\ell} X\to X/\ell$, and this induces a long exact sequence in homology.

Comment: This shows that the mod $\ell$-reduction of homology, $H_*(X)/\ell$, maps injectively into $H_*(X/\ell)$, so if the latter is finitely generated, so is the former.

Comment: Right that makes sense - but it's not clear to me how to go from there to finite generation of $H_*(X)$. It seems like this reduces it to the same question about discrete $\mathbb Z_\ell$-modules, but I don't know how to prove that either

Comment: That's a completely elementary exercise, you just check that a map between discrete $\ell$-complete $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-modules is surjective if it is surjective mod $\ell$.

Comment: That's not entirely clear to me : if I'm not mistaken, even if the modules are discrete, $\ell$-complete refers to derived $\ell$-completion, not "discrete" $\ell$-completion, right ? (of course if they are "discrete" $\ell$-complete, then I agree it's an elementary statement, but what I must be missing is the derived statement)

Comment: (let me make my doubts about the derived statement more apparent : let $M\to N$ be a map of discrete derived $\ell$-complete modules which is surjective mod $\ell$. Let $K$ be its fiber (a priori nondiscrete) - we would like to show that $K$ is connective, in which case $M\to N$ is indeed surjective. By tensoring with $\mathbb Z/\ell$, and then doing the usual extension game, we get that $K\otimes \mathbb Z/\ell^n$ is connective - $K$ is also (derived) $\ell$-complete, so it's a limit of a tower of connective modules, but as far as I can tell, this does not suffice

Comment: we would need $\varprojlim^1_n \mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb Z_\ell}_1(\pi_{-1}(K), \mathbb Z/\ell^n)$ to vanish or something like that, but this is not clear to me. Maybe it follows because $\pi_{-1}(K)$ is also derived $\ell$-complete, and maybe this implies a Mittag-Leffler condition ? Anyways, I'm still missing part of the argument)

Comment: Ah, I see, that's a subtlety I missed, sorry. But I think for a derived $K$-complete complex you can check connectivity mod $\ell$. To see this, assume $K/\ell$ is connective. Then $\pi_k K$ for $k<0$ are divisible. But they are also derived $\ell$-complete, and so they are zero.

Comment: Ah, I guess one can directly make this explicit: Your $\mathrm{Tor}_1$ is just the $\ell^n$-torsion subgroup of $\pi_{-1}(K)$, and the latter is divisible, so the maps in the diagram for your $\lim^1$ are all surjective.
By the way, using that connectivity is detected mod $\ell$ one can also directly do the original question: For $X$ $\ell$-complete with perfect mod $\ell$-reduction, inductively build a finite complex of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ with map to $X$, which induces an  equivalence mod $\ell$. This is formally similar to how one builds minimal CW approximations etc.

Comment: Oh that's neat ! I hadn't realized that divisibility was enough, I thought I needed unique divisibility. Now I think I have everything, thanks ! (and sorry for the prolonged discussion in the comments)

Comment: (I don't know what the etiquette is about answers where some more details are added in the comments - maybe you [ or I, if you'd rather I did it ] can edit it to add a word or two ? )